# Visual Studio designer not recognising assembly reference

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, designer, assembly-references

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and building a WPF application. 
Some times, the designer view doesn't load and gives error regarding assembly references. 
But, all the assembly references are in there respective path and the application compiles without error. 
Can anyone tell me how this can be resolved? 
I think it is a visual Studio issue.

Comment: This usually happens when you have a build error or haven't built yet. The designer will load the actual assembly in memory and thus needs the solution to compile properly.

Comment: This can also happen when your code base is situated on a network drive.

Comment: Strange, I neither have build error nor I have code in Network drive. It is in my local drive.